# Is it possible to figure out which corpse you're missing via the Lore?

Tags: hunted-the-demons-forge

While aimlessly browsing around in the Select menu, I noticed that when you go into the Lore, the entries are all organized in order on the bottom bar (you get missing entries in the middle). Counting from the left, I'm missing the 23rd entry. By general logic, I assumed I have missed the 23rd corpse in the game. So I loaded up Chapter 3.3 (which is where the 23rd corpse was in the guide) and I already had all the corpses in that chapter. I have everything in 3.4 as well.

I was wondering if the entries in the Lore correspond to certain bodies within the game? I figure they should since the same body always says the same thing over and over no matter how many times you talk to it, why wouldn't it always award the same entry when you find it? If this is true, has anyone figured out which Lore entries correspond to each corpse in the game? It would make it a heck of a lot easier finding your missing corpses, to at least appease one of the collectible trophies...